# How to use like operator on values fetched by sub query in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am having a table named Department.where I have column named DepartmentId,DepartmentName etc.

I have another table called Student.

```
select studentId,
       (select departmentName 
        from department 
        where DepartmentId = t.depaartmentId)as deparmnentName 
from table student;
```

Now i need to add a like operator on this department name as filter condition but i am getting error.

```
select studentId, 
       (select departmentName 
        from department 
        where DepartmentId = t.depaartmentId)as deparmnent Name 
from table student 
where departmentName like '%ph%'
```

I am new to postgres can anyone help me in this.

Comment: You need an *inner join* of the two tables.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a  join

```
select a.studentId, b.departmentName
from table student  a
INNER JOIN department b ON a.DepartmentId b.DepaartmentId
where b.departmentName like '%ph%'
```